# Escapes in python and writing

Tags: python, escaping

I'm looking for an answer on the following line of code:

```
targetfile.write(line1,\nline2,\nline3)
```

I'm trying to write to `targetfile` using escapes for each line.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
targetfile.write(line1 + "\n" + line2 + "\n" + line3)
```

You may use `sep` attribute .

```
targetfile.write(line1,line2,line3, sep="\n")
```

Comment: `targetfile.write(line1,line2,line3, sep="\n")`

Answer (score 0):

You can str.format, passing in the variables, you also need to add a trailing newline or you will get two lines written to the same line:

```
targetfile.write("{}\n{}\n{}\n".format(line1,line2,line3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `join`:

```
targetfile.write('\n'.join([line1, line2, line3]))
```